# Dataset of Luna and Emperor Moths

Tags: data-request, ontology

To implement a classifier, I require labeled data.

The features I require in the dataset are the *mass* of the moths and *wingspan*.

Additional features *antenna size* and *wing color(s)* would also be useful.

Luna Moth : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actias_luna
average wingspan: 114 mm

Emperor Moth: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturnia_pavonia
average wingspans: 60 mm (males) and 80 mm (females)

I also need the mass param for the other axis.

Answer (score 1):

As you are looking for open data you may not get all that you desire and this species of moth appears to be found only in the USA, so you should be looking for websites recording species in the USA.

Not being an US citizen or lepidopterist my searching ended up at the [GBIF website](https://www.gbif.org/) I also found this [catalogue](https://www.biodiversitycatalogue.org/) of portals type website which may be of use in future searchings?

Answer (score 1):

The [Encyclopedia of Life](https://eol.org) includes a database called TraitBank that includes some of these quantitative traits. For example, the entry for [Luna Moth](https://eol.org/pages/390368/data) has a wingspan entry but unfortunately no mass. EOL is queryable via API or SPARQL.